# AOSP - copy sh from /system/bin to /sbin (recovery-ramdisk)

Tags: android-source

I wonder how to place the copy of sh binary in recovery ramdisk (to get shell without mounting system and vendor partitions under recovery) ?

sh module is in external/mksh, it is compiled and placed in system/bin/ location.
I would like to place a copy of it in /sbin (recovery ramdisk).
I don't want to simply copy it using PRODUCT_COPY_FILES because I believe it is not a correct way to make copies in product output folder (f.e. what if system partition has not been already prepared ?!).

I was trying to include sh mksh Android.mk in recovery Android.mk but it complains the module has been already build.

Do you know the way to make it without modification of aosp original code (so by adding something to device specific files or (worse solution) by patching ) ?!

Regards!